# The method 'toStringAsFixed' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'

Tags: flutter, dart

The method 'toStringAsFixed' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.

```
amount.toStringAsFixed(2)
```

while accessing amount double value with "toStringAsFixed(2)" the result have to be a a double with decimal rounded to 2 digit.

Answer (score 1):

It means `amount` can be null so you can't always do it. Dart has null safety in its language. Meaning it prevents code to compile when it detects that you are using a method on an object that might be null. Learn more about it here: https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety

So solve it there are a couple of posibilties. If you are 100% sure that it can't be null at that line of code you can write

```
amount!.toStringAsFixed(2)
```

With the `!` you indicate that you are sure it's not null. Note that your program will crash when it does happen to be null.

You can also write

```
amount?.toStringAsFixed(2)
```

This is basically the same as

```
amount != null ? amount.toStringAsFixed(2) : null
```

So, when amount is null it returns null, otherwise the method you want.

The safest solution is probably to write it like

```
amount?.toStringAsFixed(2) ?? ""
```

Whatever you write after the `??` will act as a fallback value. It returns this when amount is null

Answer (score 0):

can be fixed using Null-aware operator `?`

```
amount?.toStringAsFixed(2)
```